# column titles come up when looking at each row in R data frame object

Tags: r, dataframe

This is probably a really basic question but I have a data frame, X with column names, the data frame is all numerical values, and I am trying to sum up all the rows, but when I look at one of the rows by using

```
X[1,]
```

foe example, it returns not only the numerical values in the first row, but also the name of each column. So this makes using

```
rowSums(X[1,])
```

impossible since it doesn't recognize the cells as numerical values.

In fact, even if I look at an individual cell:

```
X[1,1]
```

It returns the numerical value of that cell along with the line :

```
213 Levels: 1.505 1.545 1.57 1.6 1.61 1.62 1.63 1.64 1.68 1.69 1.7 1.72 1.725 1.73 1.75 1.76 1.78 1.83 ... 922472(P)
```

So i'm not really sure how to make it so that working with the data frame is more like working with a matrix, I tried:

```
m<-as.matrix(X)
```

But this doesn't fix any of the problems I'm having.

**update** I'm not sure how to best provide an example of the data due to its size, hopefully this is ok:

```
prices.names[1:5,1:5]
   AWE ADELAIDE.BRIGHTON RAMSAY.HEALTH.CARE AUS.AND.NZ.BANKING.GP.  AMCOR
1  1.8               1.7             7.0127                  20.59 6.2342
2 1.75              1.75               7.19                  20.62 6.2935
3  1.9              1.76             7.2491                  20.34 6.2257
4 1.79              1.72             7.0423                   20.2 6.0815
5  1.8              1.83             7.1014                  20.55 6.0815
```

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example, right now we are guessing as much as you.

Comment: Please check if you imported your data correctly. It seems like they are a factor.

Comment: @Heroka Yes, they are factors, why does that make it incorrect? Is there a way to transform it to a matrix of numerical values but maintain the titles, for example: y<-matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)),nrow=nrow(x)), convers to numerica vlaues but also removes the titles which i want

Comment: @PaulHiemstra please see update

Comment: @dimebucker91 it's not incorrect per sé, but impractical. I assume you want to operate on the numbers that are the current value-labels --> easier to read them in as numeric or convert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform first to a matrix of numbers, if you want to keep the general structure, you could try this:

```
prices.names <- sapply(prices.names, function(r) as.numeric(as.character(r)))
```

If you would like to have a `data.frame` anyway, you could wrap the previous call in `as.data.frame()`, like so:

```
prices.names <- as.data.frame(sapply(prices.names, function(r) as.numeric(as.character(r))))
```

Afterwards `rowSums` should work as expected:

```
> rowSums(prices.names[1,])
      1 
37.3369 


> rowSums(prices.names)
[1] 37.3369 37.6035 37.4748 36.8338 37.3629

> apply(prices.names,1,sum)
[1] 37.3369 37.6035 37.4748 36.8338 37.3629
```

You could save this output in an object as well:

```
> rs <- rowSums(prices.names)
> rs[1]
[1] 37.3369
> rs[2]
[1] 37.6035
> rs[3]
[1] 37.4748
> rs[4]
[1] 36.8338
> rs[5]
[1] 37.3629
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Collection  <- data.frame(A=seq(1,10), B=seq(11,20),C=seq(21,30))
rowSums(Collection[1,])
```

gives

```
 1 
33
```

it gives the sum of the row and the name of that row.

Whilst,

```
rowSums(Collection)
 [1] 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60
```

is what you want?

Comment: I get the error 'x' must be numeric when i try to apply rowSums, to both the row and to the entire data frame, is there maybe  a way to change the class of all elements of the data frame, currently they are all factors, whereas in 'Collection' they are integers

Comment: Provide an example of your data.  I suspect the factors appeared at your data input step when you used read.table() or read.csv() (or similar).  If you use the argument, stringsAsFactors=FALSE your factors should disappear.  But you most probably need to subset the resulting data.frame() to only include the numerical values that you're trying to sum.  But without an example, I'm only guessing.